# Show all options in JQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Goal: make suggest field in form when user types his adress

Yandex maps instead of Google. I wrote all js for handling data from yandex but got one problem

for example user types:
New-York

and gets suggest:
New-York
New-York, Manhattan

all fine.

but when he continues typing to:
New-York manhatt

he gets suggest:
New-York, Manhattan
New-York, Manhattan, Empire Satate Building

Suggest works fine BUT
results don't show in sugget list cause string user typed - "New-York manhatt" 
doesn't match any part of the string from suggest
"New-York manhatt" != part of "New-York, Manhattan"
"New-York manhatt" != part of "New-York, Manhattan, Empire Satate Building"

So, all i need is to show to user all data from suggest independent from what he typed

ideas?

Comment: If the problem is solved, maybe you could post the solution as an answer so everyone can benefit.